# Synchronize files over LAN from client to server

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

[image]

As shown in the above image. I have a server and few clients connected in on a LAN. Clients contain a folder which contains files/images. I want to synchronize all the files from client to single folder at server.

I searched for a solution the web, but no clear ideas on how to implement. I am not familiar with how synchronization works and I don't have idea what is BITS and how it works.

Is there any way to use a Windows Forms Application and Wcf/C# to do this?

Comment: BITS is for C and C++ devs. I would suggest you use [Observer pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee850490(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I would reccomend using a existing library instead of trying to implment it yourself, for example the [Microsoft Sync Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx) can be easily called from C# code and do this kind of work.

Comment: Hi  @scott-chamberlain, Thanks for your reply, but i am new to it, do you have any reference or sample example which i can refer or links to plz share